# AWK comparing string date value from task list to today's date

Tags: regex, date, awk, match

I have a todo.txt task list that I'd like to filter on to show any tasks scheduled for dates in the future or today, i.e. - show no past dates scheduled and only show tasks which have a date scheduled.

The file lines and orders change sometimes to include a 'threshold (think snooze/postpone task until...) date in format: t:date +%Y-%m-%d which says, 'don't start this task until this date'.

Data file:

```
50 (A) Testing due date due:2018-09-22 t:2018-09-25
04 (B) Buy Socks, Underwear t:2018-09-22
05 (B) Buy Vaporizer t:2018-09-23 due:2018-09-22
16 (C) Watch Thor Ragnarock
12 (B) Pay Electric Bill due:2018-09-20 t:2018-09-25
x 2018-09-21 pri:B Buy Prebiotics +health @web due:2018-09-21
```

So far I've come up with this:

```
cat t | awk -F: -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" '/due:|t:/ $2 >= date || $3 >= date { print $0}'|
nl
```

Problem is, The date comparison is working on the “due:” field as it usually comes before “t:” field. Also, entries older then today are output.

Output:

```
 1  50 (A) Testing due date due:2018-09-22 t:2018-09-25
 2  05 (B) Buy Vaporizer t:2018-09-23 due:2018-09-22
 3  12 (B) Pay Electric Bill due:2018-09-20 t:2018-09-25
```

Questions:

1. How do I correctly make the date comparison against "t:" value after the “:” separator if “t:” is present - and on the “due:” value if “t:” is not present?
2. Date greater than (“>”) seems to work but equal to does not (“>=“)

Comment: So what's the actual question here -- to parse the input list and return only the lines where the current date is after the latest date on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    orig = $0
    sched = ""
    for (i=NF; i>0; i--) {
        if ( sub(/^t:/,"",$i) ) {
            sched = $i
            break
        }
        else if ( sub(/^due:/,"",$i) ) {
            sched = $i
        }
    }
    $0 = orig
}
sched >= date

$ awk -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -f tst.awk file
50 (A) Testing due date due:2018-09-22 t:2018-09-25
05 (B) Buy Vaporizer t:2018-09-23 due:2018-09-22
12 (B) Pay Electric Bill due:2018-09-20 t:2018-09-25
```

Comment: That's done the trick. Ed, for all us non awk gurus, can you explain in words the general methodology of what your script is doing?

Comment: Expanding this script:
Sometimes I want to know tasks ">=" and at other times, "<" or just "==".
Question: How can your script accommodate this?

Comment: It's just looking for fields that start with t: or due: working back from the end of the line. When it finds due: it remembers the dat and keeps looking for t:. When it finds t: it remembers the date and stops looking. Then it just compares the date from the input (sched) against the date input and if the result is true invokes the default action of printing the current line.

Comment: wrt your 2nd comment - just change the `>=` in the code to do whatever comparison you want.

Comment: I tried writing that line as "sched comparison date" and then adding the variable like so (awk -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -v comparison=">=" -f ./date.awk) but didn't work for me.

Comment: [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are generally frowned upon. Post a new question with it's own [mcve] explaining what you want to do now with it's own concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Understand. I thought my last question was still "closely related" but that's fine.

Comment: It's somewhat related but there's no testable sample input and expected output or clearly stated requirements for what you're now asking about so I'd be guessing at what you actually want, have no way of testing a possible solution, and providing a 2nd answer that's not related to your original question will make it harder for people in future to find/understand the 1st answer or the 2nd one and idk if you'll have another "Expanding this script..." request after this so all things considered it's best just to take it one clear, simple question at a time.