# AWK equality comparison of two string variables fails

Tags: string, variables, awk, comparison

Today's date is:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
echo $DATE
2018-09-26
```

I have this awk script named z.awk:

```
{
    orig = $0
    sched = ""
    for (i=NF; i>0; i--)
    {
        if ( sub(/^t:/,"",$i) )
        {
            sched = $i
            #print sched
            break
        }
        else if ( sub(/^due:/,"",$i) )
        {
            sched = $i
        }
    }
    $0 = orig
}
sched == date
```

DATA FILE (./t):

```
33 (A) How to build a time machine t:2018-09-27 due:2018-09-26
02 (A) Search the IT Jobs due:2018-09-20
32 (B) AWS Cost Explorer +customerX due:2018-09-26
05 (B) Barclays Gaget Protection t:2018-09-24
37 (B) Barclay’s App Reregister t:2018-09-24 due:2018-09-22
34 (B) Book winter sun flights t:2018-09-25 due:2018-09-25
03 (B) Buy Raspberry Pi 3 t:2018-09-22
04 (B) Buy Vaporizer +health @web t:2018-09-27 due:2018-09-22
38 (B) Dr Apt - Change dates! t:2018-09-29
```

COMMAND:

```
cat ./t | awk -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -f z.awk
```

OUTPUT:

```
32 (B) AWS Cost Explorer +customerX due:2018-09-26
```

COMMAND:

```
grep -e "t:$DATE"  -e "due:$DATE" ./t
```

OUTPUT:

```
33 (A) How to build a time machine t:2018-09-27 due:2018-09-26
32 (B) AWS Cost Explorer +customerX due:2018-09-26
```

GREP does a logical OR comparison and gives me an extra line of output which (today's due: date) which I'm not interested in since I've postponed that task until tomorrow now - snooze button.

With the AWK script, data from my real un-sanitised task list gives me no output on the equal to comparison ("sched == date"), where as on the sanitised task list data provided, it works. Same goes for greater than or equal to "sched > date" always gives me todays date in addition.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Is this the right way to go about comparing date string variables or is there a better way?

FURTHER INFORMATION

Okay, I've found the problem: My sample data does not reflect fully what the todo.txt-cli script that I am running actually does.

My command is actually:

```
todo.sh ls | awk -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -f z.awk.
```

[Gina Trapani](https://ginatrapani.org/)'s amazing [todo.txt format](https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt) todo list manager ([todo.sh](http://todotxt.org/)) outputs ANSI COLOR characters at the beginning and end of each line, like so:

```
^[[0;32m40 (B) A/C Fixed? +fittings @web @cal^[[0m
^[[0;32m4343 (B) Pay Rent +finance @web t:2018-09-27 due:2018-09-26^[[0m
^[[0;32m42 (B) Make Calls +workship @call t:2018-09-27^[[0m
^[[0;32m41 (B) Flying Lessons - Book +sports @apts due:2018-09-27^[[0m
```

So I guess the awk script needs to ignore end of line chars "^[[0m" when making comparison operations?

Comment: The awk script is behaving correctly per your requirements from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52462125/1745001) that the `t:` value should be the only one used when both the `t:` and `due;` dates are present on a line. The first line of grep output in your question should NOT be output because **the date** to be used for comparison in that line is the `t:` one of `2018-09-27` which is not equal to todays date of `2018-09-26`. The only line that should be output is the one the awk script does output. So yes the code is correct and it's not clear why you're asking.

Comment: Update your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
}
$0 = orig
```

to this:

```
}
sched = substr(sched,1,10)
$0 = orig
```

to trim any trailing chars from sched.

Comment: That all works as expected now. Would make it complete if you could explain a little on the final part of this script and clarify what do the two lines "$0 = orig" & "orig = $0" actually do?

Comment: The sub()s are modifying $0 so you need to save it before that happens and restore it afterwards if you want to continue with it as it originally was.

Comment: well yeah but also if we didn't save and restore it then the output of `date == sched` would be the modified instead of original $0. There's other ways to solve it too of course.

Comment: Okay, so am I correct in thinking that the sub() command essentially removes the “t:” or “due:” from the regex match (i.e. leaving only the %Y-%m-%d in this case) from the (whole) input line $0 and therefore the output would be missing these tags and so this is why we have the line to reset the $0 output to its original value? Now we have captured the date value from the input line and cast it to the “sched” variable for later use in our comparison operations where we compare our value to that of today's date which I pass into the program's “date” variable upon invocation.

Comment: right. you can always add before/after print statements all over the script if you're not sure what any given line does.